# Why might an MFC application be scaled differently on two machines with the same resolution?

Tags: windows, mfc, dialog, scaling, resolution

I develop an MFC application running on Windows 10.

Under development, the application looks as expected on our machines using 1920x1080 monitors.

One of our users reports that some MFC dialogs are scaled incorrectly on a new laptop (HP EliteBook 840 G8) with the same monitor resolution (1920x1080).

The machine is brand-new so it is unlikely that the default font has been changed.

The user reports that the computer is set to 100% scaling with text scaling set to 'smallest'. As far as we can tell, we have exactly the same scaling settings.

How could it be that the MFC dialog is not taking the same scaling on the user's machine?

I do understand that MFC dialogs are scaled in 'dialog units', but the customer has indicated that this is a brand-new laptop and should be using the default Windows system font, therefore we should be seeing the same scaling.

My next step will be to confirm the system font on the user's computer. Have I missed any factors which may affect MFC dialog scaling?

---

Updates:

- This user has 1x built-in 1920x1080 monitor and 2x external 1920x1080 monitors
- The system was installed with a clean copy of Windows 10 but then files were copied over from their previous system by IT, so it's not exactly untouched, although the user believes the OS was not modified (to be confirmed)
- There seem to be a variety of ways to adjust display scaling on Windows 10, but it looks like at least 2 of them are just different ways to access the same setting. @IInspectable points out that there is both a 'Scale and layout' setting and a 'Make everything bigger' setting on another page. When I change either of these values, I get the same result, which happens to be the opposite of what the user is reporting. Additionally, if I change one value e.g. to 125%, the other one then appears at 125%. Therefore I believe it is the same setting.

---

Example of the how the dialog is intended to look:
[image]

Example of how the dialog looks when scaled incorrectly on the user PC (note - pay attention to the icons which are visible, not the size of the image which I uploaded. The user sent a very low-res screenshot.):
[image]

Example of how the dialog looks when I increase monitor scaling to 125% on my own monitor:
[image]

Comment: The font will make a big difference. Because dialogs are writting in DLUs and not pixels. Based on the font, the DLUs scale to differently sized dialogs. Typically, your dialog might be using MS Shell Dlg or MS Shell Dlg 2. Those are aliases which you can use the registry to lookup what font they are. HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\FontSubstitutes You can call GetFont() in your InitInstance of your dialog to the the CFont* (C++ rep for HFONT). Then from there call GetLogFont() to get the LOGFONT and look at the differences between the two systems.

Comment: Could you post a screen shot of both situations?

Comment: 1. Show us some screen shots to give us context. 2. Add some debug code to display / log all the graphic credentials so you actually know what the application is using for rendering.

Answer (score 0):

Windows Display Zoom settings affects dialog sizes (and their fonts, controls).  This is different than selecting the System Font

[image]

Comment: I have checked this (this is what I meant by "set to 100% scaling".

Comment: @afa There's also a setting under *System* / *Display* called *Scale and layout*. I would suspect that to be set to 100% as well on a 1920x1080 display, though you should probably verify.

Comment: @IInspectable It seems that there are 2 ways of changing the same setting under Settings. Whether I change 'Scale and layout' or 'Make everything bigger', the UI reacts in the same way, which happens to be the *opposite* of what our user is complaining about. 

No combination of scaling under 'Make everything bigger' or 'Scale and layout' allows me to reproduce what the user is showing.